# How to trigger a relay and LED when a certain threshold of 0.15 volts is passed

Tags: voltage

I am learning electronics so this question is learners question. So what is a circuit (referred to as A) that does the following. It has two input wires (say a DC battery for example) , from some circuit referred to as B,  which is a input voltage source to A . When this source voltage exceeds 0.15 volts then a 5v relay is turned and and also an led (that needs a minimum of 1.2 volts to work). The LED is turned fully on with no flickering. The input voltage,into A, can range from between 0 to 6 volts. The power supply for the circuit A is isolated from B power supply meaning  it does not power B  (from which the two input wires come from). A has an independent power supply.  The circuit is to use the LM339N-which seems right to use- which I dont fully understand so far how it work. So I am asking this question on here.  I dont need a fancy answer-just an answer that show how to use LM339N in a clear way to make the circuit.

Comment: Draw a schematic!

Comment: The LM339N is a comparator. Use the typical comparator circuit to compare two voltages. That's it.

Comment: Consult the LM339N datasheet - there should be example circuits there that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi0Zkm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So in the schematic i've drawn, you get the behaviour you have requested.

From left to right:
Input signal (0 - 6V) goes through R1 as a current-limiter, and is clamped to 5V maximum by a 5V Zener diode D1. This is useful to protect the input of your op-amp/comparator. The resistor R6 next to the zener diode ensures the signal input will be pulled low if it floats and will stop strange behaviour on the output relay etc. The protected signal then goes into the non-inverting input of a general purpose op-amp which is in an "open loop" or basically "comparator" mode, where if:

A (non-inverting "+" input) > B (inverting, "-" input) , OUTPUT = HIGH (~5V)

If A < B, then OUTPUT = LOW (~0V).

I have a voltage divider made from Supply A's voltage level, to give 0.15V from 5V through the divider (10k and 310Ohm). This is a "reference" voltage that lets us trigger the logic change at above or below 0.15V.

The op-amp is a general purpose, single-supply op-amp which will work fine in this diagram as shown. The supply capacitor C1 for it is important, for any IC you use - always have this as close as you can to the VCC and GND pins.

The output of the op-amp has a pull-down resistor to give it a load, and a discharge path for the MOSFET M1's gate if for some reason the MCP6001 goes high-impedence. It may be removed if you don't want it.

The output of the op-amp then goes to the gate of N-channel MOSFET "M1". This mosfet acts as a "power switch", in a "low side" configuration. This means that the power switch completes the connection of the "Load" to "ground", to allow current to flow. The load is the relay coil (L1) (with protection diode D2) and the LED with a series resistor to limit the LED current. if it's a red LED using only 1.2V and with a 5V supply, to limit the current to 10mA the resistor should be around 330 or 470 Ohms.

The part used in this first circuit is not really what you wanted, but actually the MCP6001 op-amp is probably better than the LM339 comparator for a newbie to start with, because the LM339 uses an open-drain output logic which is annoying because it inverts the logic, whereas the MCP6001 uses a standard 'push-pull' style output which is easier to understand what a logic HIGH and LOW is. You can simply use a P-channel MOSFET (or PNP BJT) for the LM339 though and a different way of using the resistor R4, i'll show that version below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKqBfE.png)</sup>

This second version with an open-drain comparator like the LM339 uses a P-channel MOSFET arranged as a "high side switch". This connects the load to the positive power supply (B), and ground in this case is always connected unlike in the last circuit. The high side switch is actually preferable for many more types of loads than a low-side switch, just because some loads do not enjoy having their ground removed, but basically any circuit is fine with the positive power supply rail being removed (switched off).

Comment: Your first circuit won't work. It violates TL081 common-mode limits badly. Or rather, if it does work it will be a mark of undeserved luck on your part.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast oh jeez, you are right. I just looked at the datasheet more closely and it's flippin terrible. I will change it to a different op-amp. I was being lazy and tried to justify the Circuitlab default op-amp part which is clearly a poor choice for many purposes, damn circuitlab.

Comment: @KyranF Does the LM339 opamp have accuracy limits for? For example could 0.0000015 volts be used instead of 0.15 volts as the threshold voltage? Similarly can the threshold voltage be arbitrarily close to 6 volts?-if B is powered by a 6v power supply. I see B can also be an AC power source from your schematic. So what are the frequency limits of the sine wave for an LM339?

Comment: @Pete The threshold is adjusted with the resistor divider - you can simply  use a potentiometer wiper ( with 5v to the top of pot, gnd on the bottom) as a variable 0-5V reference. The MCP6001 op-amp and the LM339 comparator BOTH will have input-offset voltage inaccuracies and the comparator probably has "hysteresis" which is great for noisy signals but can mean you have a wider band of on/off accuracy. The limitations on resolution would be in the < 10 millivolt range.

Comment: @KyranF  So the hysteresis makes it accurate to millivolts range or about 0.001*10 or 0.01 volts. and the  input-offset voltage inaccuracies would shift the value of 0.01 either way a little. Why is  mosfet required? Is it  because it leaks less current than a common npn signal transistor? Could I use a 2N7002 mosfet? I have a bc 547 transistor-what are disadvantage of using that-if any instead of a mosfet?

Comment: @Pete the advantages of a FET compared to BJT transistor is there is no continuous power to hold it on or off, they drop far less voltage across them (so dissipate less energy, P = V*I and FET has less V than a BJT by a factor of 10 or more easily) during operation as a "switch". You are switching "power loads" not a small-signal. The next thing, is yes, your threshold will be accurate probably to around +-5mV of the target, depends on the op-amp though. Input offset voltage can simply be servo'd out with the potentiometer. You want a 10+ turn pot for the resolution though.

Comment: @Pete as for the "AC power source" i'm not sure what you mean by that. If you refer to my "input signal" being a sine wave, that was just so if you were to simulate it, you can see it in action as the input signal crosses above and below the reference voltage.

Comment: @Pete the accuracy the limit for op-amps and comparators is called "offset voltage" and can be found in the data sheet.  If you need extreme precision you may find that an *instrumentation amplifier* is possibly what you want